# A good primer for Concrete Mathematics?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, soft-question, computer-science

I've been watching MIT's Mathematics for Computer Science, from Fall 2010 whilst reading Concrete Mathematics. Honestly the topic seems like a hodgepodge of ideas. I can follow about 2/3 of the material quite well so far but the other 1/3 is a big hurdle. At my current college nothing but calculus, differential equations and linear algebra are offered.

I'm currently in a Calculus III course which covers series, but my question is if I were to step back and build a primer for discrete math, combinatorics and graph theory(math subjects with applications to computer science as I am a CS student pursuing a math minor) how might I start doing that?

I have watched all of Gilbert Strang's and Norman Wildberg's lectures on linear algebra, while also having done a lot of work through Strang's and Lay's textbook. I feel like at my level that my Linear is quite strong as I can tutor it despite not having taken the course yet.

What is a direction that I could go that would be productive use of my time? I am not the best calculus student as I find that subject quite boring and not as applicable for computer science as far as I've seen. I guess I'm not only looking for a list of textbooks? Are there good books on nurturing a thinking process of doing the sort of math I asked? I've read Proof and Refutations by Imre Lakatos and have checked out Pólya's How to Solve It.

Comment: "Mathematics for CS" is supposed to be a hodgepodge; by its definition, it is those parts of mathematics which are currently considered useful in CS. (For instance, combinatorics, asymptotics, linear algebra, cryptography, logic, category theory.) Your question should specify the exact subjects you are having trouble with and the exact subjects you want to learn.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'm sorry if my question was not direct enough. My question is:  what is the math, if math is a discipline that is hierarchical, is a step below concrete mathematics? I'm looking to strengthen my base so I will have a better foundation.

Comment: A Maths for CS text, if sufficiently elementary, can be the first math text you read (although it doesn't have to be, and not all of them are sufficiently elementary). Here is one such text that *should* do the trick: Lehman, Leighton, Meyer, *Mathematics for Computer Science*, http://people.csail.mit.edu/meyer/mcs.pdf . If you want to play it safe, you can read one of the many introductions to proofs (e.g., Chartrand, Polimeni, Zhang, *Mathematical Proofs: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics*, or Daepp, Gorkin, *Reading, Writing, and Proving*, just to mention two such texts; ...

Comment: ... I have no personal experience with any of them).

Comment: @darijgrinberg I'll check that out thank you. Most of what I've been doing so far is elementary, but when it isn't elementary its hard when you self study to rigorously learn a subject when there are gaps.